# $X_{n}$ and $Z$ be random variables if $X_{n} \ge Z$ then $ E[\liminf_{n\to \infty} X_{n}] \le \liminf_{n\to \infty} E[X_{n}] $

Tags: integration, probability-theory, limsup-and-liminf, expectation

Let $X_{n}$ and $Z$ be random variables on probability space $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,P)$ and $Z$ be integrable. Show that $$X_{n} \ge Z \qquad \Longrightarrow \qquad E[\liminf_{n\to \infty}  X_{n}] \le \liminf_{n\to \infty}  E[X_{n}] $$

Comment: Use `\liminf`. $ $

Comment: @Did.ok thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fatou's lemma applied to the non-negative sequence $X_n-Z$.